# How do you check the size of a disk and its max number of inodes

Tags: linux, ext4

I just had a computer crash I think because I exceeded the max number of files. Eventually I would like to increase the number of inodes of a drive as this person has done

https://serverfault.com/questions/724864/how-to-increase-max-number-of-allocated-inodes-in-linux

but for now, I need to understand that I'm reading the computer's data right.

```
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   10G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   10G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0  200G  0 disk 
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks$ df -i /dev/sdb
Filesystem       Inodes IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           15469823   288 15469535    1% /dev
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks$ df -T -h /dev/sdb
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   60G     0   60G   0% /dev
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks$ df -i /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      655360 142612 512748   22% /
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks$ df -T -h /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4  9.8G  2.5G  6.9G  27% /
```

The drive `sdb` has 200G and I want to find out how many inodes it has.  For this command

```
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks$ df -i /dev/sdb
    Filesystem       Inodes IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
    udev           15469823   288 15469535    1% /dev
```

I would think that that means I have 15 million inodes on the drive `sdb`, but that does not explain why my computer crashed with the error message `not enough space`, since I created I think around 200,000 files.  The other computer I was using had another drive with the same specifications.  But when I try to get the size of the `sdb` drive with

```
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks$ df -T -h /dev/sdb
    Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev           devtmpfs   60G     0   60G   0% /dev
```

I says 60G rather than 200G.  Why?  I then try the mountpoint of the external harddrive which is `/mnt/disks/temp_dir1` with the following commands:

```
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks$ df -i /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
    Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
    /dev/sda1      655360 142612 512748   22% /
```

That says 655,000 inodes which seems like a number which might have caused my computer to crash.  The drive is empty even though 142,000 inodes are being used, so maybe the creation of one file uses more than one inode or perhaps there are more hidden files.  In any case, why are there only 655,000 inodes on `/mnt/disks/temp_dir` and 15 million on `/dev/sdb`? I then try to check that the size of `/mnt/disks/temp_dir1` is 200G so I write:

```
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks$ df -T -h /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
    Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda1      ext4  9.8G  2.5G  6.9G  27% /
```

And I seems that the size is 9.8G rather than 200G.  10G is also the size of the harddrive I'm using which might explain things.  Perhaps I didn't mount the harddrive to the mount point but that is false due to the following command:

```
kylefoley@c30:~$ gcloud compute instances attach-disk c30 --disk disk-3 --zone us-west2-a
Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/atomic-drake-250022/zones/us-west2-a/instances/c30].
```

---

UPDATE

---

I think last time after attaching the disk I forgot to mount the disk.  This time around I have more reasonable numbers:

```
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks/temp_dir1$ df -i /dev/sdb
Filesystem       Inodes IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       13107200 36981 13070219    1% /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks/temp_dir1$ df -T h /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
df: h: No such file or directory
Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       ext4 205375464 229888 205129192   1% /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks/temp_dir1$ df -T -h /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       ext4  196G  225M  196G   1% /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
kylefoley@c30:/mnt/disks/temp_dir1$ df -i /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
Filesystem       Inodes IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       13107200 36981 13070219    1% /mnt/disks/temp_dir1
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that in drive `/mnt/disks/temp_dir1` I have 13 million inodes.  And 196G.  That's not as many inodes as I want.  I want to use 12 million but just to be on safe side I'd better build a new disk with more inodes.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `df` is a **file object**, and `df` displays information about the filesystem holding that object. When you do `df /dev/sdb`, `df` shows you the information for the pseudo-filesystem `/dev`.

What you need to do is to enter:

```
mount | grep '/dev/sdb'
```

To find out where the file system in `/dev/sdb` is mounted, for instance:

```
/dev/sdb on /mnt/somedir type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Then use `df /mnt/somedir` to obtain the relevant filesystem information (but given the `lsblk` output, there is nothing mounted.

However, since the `df` output for `mnt/disks/temp_dir1` reports that it is on `sda1`, like the root, it is likely a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) (more or less a "hard link" to a directory) (the `mount` output will report several filesystems on /dev/sda1, the root and any bind mounts).

Comment: If the hd was not mounted then why did I get this output   
 `kylefoley@c30:~$ gcloud compute instances attach-disk c30 --disk disk-3 --zone us-west2-a  
Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/atomic-drake-250022/zones/us-west2-a/instances/c30]`?

Comment: See update.  I think I got it this time.

Comment: *I think I got it this time.* Indeed.

Comment: Is there a typo in first command?

Comment: Yes, missing ending quote, fixed.